# How to get the file path for a hyperlink using Java that can work both locally and on Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, path, filepath

I am building an HTML file with a hyperlink in my Java project.

```
    // log/file.html path is within the Jenkins workspace directory. $WORKSPACE/log/file.html.
    File myFile = new File("log/file.html");
    String hyperlink = myFile.getCanonicalPath();
```

**Local Mac Run:**
SUCCESS.

The html generates a hyperlink which when clicked takes me to the desired HTML page.

```
hyperlink value = file:///Users/username/workspace/ProjectName/log/file.html
```

However, when I run the Maven Java project on Jenkins, it fails.

```
hyperlink value = file:///Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/JobFolderName/JobName/log/file.html
```

Obviously, this absolute path hyperlink won't work. Nothing happens when I click on the hyperlink.

How do I change my Java code such that it works both for local machine runs as well as Jenkins with workspace relative path (irrespective of OS used - Windows/Linux/Mac)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
String hyperlink = "";

            
                File myFile = new File("log/file.html");
                if(System.getenv("BUILD_URL") == null) {
                    hyperlink = myFile.getCanonicalPath();
                }
                else{
                    hyperlink = System.getenv("BUILD_URL") + "artifact" + File.separator + "log" + File.separator + "file.html";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classpath resource instead of absolute path.

eg. assuming inside src/main/resources , you make a directory 'log' and inside that you keep your html file

```
URL fileUrl = getClass().getResource("log/file.html");
File myFile = new File(fileUrl.getFile());
String hyperlink = myFile.getCanonicalPath();
```

Comment: You should use like this.getClass().getResource(..) or if it is inside a static method then YourClass.class.getResource(..)

Comment: Tried it. Line 2 throws NullPointerException.

Comment: Tried to print the value of fileUrl. It prints as NULL.

Comment: The log folder is not inside src/main/resources though. src and log folders are peer directories under the workspace home.

Comment: If it is not in src/main/resources then this wont work. As it is taking classpath as reference to start looking into

Comment: Is there a way I can navigate to higher levels like this URL fileUrl = getClass().getResource("../../../../log/file.html");

Comment: No you cant. Then use new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/log/file.html")